# How to center a tooltip horizontally on top of a link

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to get a tooltip box to be inserted on top and centered of an a tag. I have this working for small Text, but I can't seem to get it to center on large text.

I understand it has to do with positioning the box and the arrow but I can't seem to find the right combination to get the arrow centered under the box and the box centered above the a tag.

I'm hoping to accomplish this with just CSS alone.

HTML:

```
<div> 
    <a class="tooltip" href="#" title="tooltip">
        <span>Text</span>    
    </a>

</div>
<div> <a class="tooltip" href="#" title="tooltip">
        <span>TextTextText</span>    
    </a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
    padding: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
.tooltip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    padding: 10px;
    left: -50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
}
.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

[And here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anx26/2/).

I really would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What's `#333 transparent`?

Comment: @bjb568 This is *[two-value syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color#Syntax)* `border-color: horizontal vertical;`

Comment: Oh. Who needs a transparent border?

Comment: to build the arrow for around the tooltip

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If the *tooltip* doesn't have an explicit `width`, you could align that horizontally center, by using a negative [`translateX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translateX) as follows:

```css
.tooltip:hover:after {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    /* other styles ... */
}

.tooltip:hover:before {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    /* other styles ... */
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(title);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover:before {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  bottom: 20px;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="tooltip" title="tooltip">
    <a href="#">Work</a>    
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="tooltip" title="tooltip">
    <a href="#">Doesn't Work as hoped</a>    
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: only thing missed was the -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); for IE

Comment: @dbarnes Yes you're right, and `-o-` for Opera 10.5-12.10 :)

Answer (score -1):

You might find the following link helpful. I think this will do exactly what you need:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/

They have a working example here:

http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/tooltip_demo.html

Comment: That's actually where I got some of my css from, they just didn't center the popup correctly

Answer (score -1):

I think you need tutorial to view [Create CSS3 Tooltip](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-simple-tooltip-using-css3.php) and the main code is

```
<a title="Create Simple Tooltip Using CSS3" class="tooltip">Some Sample CSS3 Tooltip</a>

.tooltip
{
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after
{
 background: #333;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 border-radius: 5px;
 bottom: 26px;
 color: #fff;
 content: attr(title);
 left: 20%;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 98;
 width: 220px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before
{
 border: solid;
 border-color: #333 transparent;
 border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
 bottom: 20px;
 content: "";
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is what I can think of now(at 1am :) ). works well with all browsers.

```
div {
padding: 150px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: red;
text-align: center;
}
.tooltip {
display: inline;
position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after {
background: #333;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 26px;
color: #fff;
content: attr(title);
padding: 10px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 98;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
}
.tooltip:hover:before {
border: solid;
border-color: #333 transparent;
border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
bottom: 20px;
right: 50%;
margin-right: -15px;
content:"";
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Regards,
Ashok