# Horizontally center span within another span in making a tooltip?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

For a given word wrapped in a `span` element, I am trying to make a tooltip appear on hover using plain CSS only (without the various tooltip functions, the reason being that I need to have LaTeX displayed within the tooltip). The tooltip itself is a `span` within its parent `span`. Currently I'm getting a tooltip that is off center (left) while I'm trying to achieve the result on the right:

[image]

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uyvet5L3/). I've tried various combination of display (inline, table, block) with auto 0 margin etc. unsuccessfully.

Comment: It may or may not meet your needs but have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709674/align-tooltip-box-horizontally-to-html-element/21709841#21709841

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following css property and let me know how that works for you:

```
.link-cont:hover .tooltip{

    display: table; 
        left: 10%;

}
```

You ought to be able to adjust to suit your needs - 10% seemed to do the trick with this particular example.

(I've updated your JS fiddle for you with the above)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your tool tip is position absolute. You can't use margin auto on absolute.

Try having your container to place the tool tip above the text absolute and then have another child element inside that is relative. You can the give that element margin auto.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly easy way to center the tool-tip is to create a wrapper `.tip-wrap` that is
a child element of the link text block `.link-cont`.  `tip-wrap` has the same width
as its parent and has `text-align: center` to center the inline-block `.tooltip`.

`.tip-wrap` is absolutely positioned just above the top border of `.link-cont`.

Since you specifiec a height of 20px, and the decorative triangle is 5px, the 
top offset is 25px.

**Note:** If your tool tip is longer than the link text, then you need to make some 
adjustments to the positioning of the `.tip-wrap`.  Specify a sufficiently long
width (the exact length does not matter), and then apply a negative margin equal
to half of the specified width.

```css
.tip-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  bottom: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.link-cont {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}
.tooltip {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.link-cont:hover .tip-wrap {
  display: block;
}
.tooltip .tooltip-triangle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
.tooltip .tooltip-triangle {
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px); /* slightly more accurate */
}
```

```html
<p>Text.
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>This is a <span class="link-cont">loooooooooooooooooooooooooong
    <span class="tip-wrap"><span class="tooltip ">the content<span class="tooltip-triangle"></span></span>
  </span>
  </span> word.</p>
<p>This is a sentence containing a <span class="link-cont">short
    <span class="tip-wrap"><span class="tooltip ">the short word content<span class="tooltip-triangle"></span></span>
  </span>
  </span> word and a few extra at the end.</p>
```